# Extracting first part of a string

Tags: c

I'm posting this as a vent for my questions (I will have a multitude). I decided it would be rather annoying to keep asking the same person one question at a time (said person is very busy), so I'll be posting questions as I come across them in my project. If you feel like helping, please do, and I would greatly appreciate it!

Note: this means I'll be updating this post frequently. Help is greatly, greatly appreciated as always.

**EDIT** so you guys want me to just keep posting different questions if I come across them? Of course I always do research before asking you guys, you talented group of men and women only get the most persistent of errors.

My first question:

I keep getting the error:

> lvalue required as left operand of assignment

**THE PURPOSE** of this code is to copy the first n character up to `':'`. For instance, if `currentline` is: `"LABEL:    .long 100"` then `GetLabelName` would return `"LABEL"`.

**NOTE** `strncpy` isn't working for this. It returns the remaining characters after ignoring the first n characters instead of just returning the first n characters...

Here's the code that's causing the error:

```
char *GetLabelName(char *currentline){
   char *labelname[200];
   while((((*labelname)++)=(*currentline)++)!=':');
   return labelname;
}
```

Something is fishy about this code I guess, but I can't figure out what. Any ideas?

Comment: Please do not "update this post frequently". That's not really what [SO] is about. Please ask a separate question for each individual question. (And it wouldn't hurt to do a wee bit of searching first, since C has been around for a while and a lot of the questions are a bit old at this point. :)

Comment: Please ask questions separately, don't sit here and edit one post to add multiple questions.

Comment: What in the world are you trying to do in that code snippet? Should `labelname` also be a `char(*)[]` or a `char[]`? Are you simply trying to return a pointer to after the `':'` in a string? Have you looked at `strchr` or `strtok`?

Comment: I'm trying to copy part of a string into another. Specifically, I want to find an assembly label, so if currentline is:
LABEL:    .long 100
i want it to return LABEL

By the way, I have tried strncpy. I'm getting a very strange error...
Instead of copying the first n characters, it skips the first n characters and returns the remaining characters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I think you're trying to do is extract/copy all of the characters in a string up until a certain point (`':'` or NUL) and return that buffer. If that's the case, you're going to need to dynamically allocate memory for the new string (you can't return a local buffer allocated on the stack), and you should also take advantage of functions in `<string.h>` like `strchr` and `memcpy`.

Here's an alternative working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *extract_string(char *str, char delim)
{
   size_t len;
   char *new_str;
   char *delim_pos = strchr(str, delim);

   /* new string is the length from the start of the old string to the
    * delimiter, or if it doesn't exist, a copy of the whole string */
   if (delim_pos == NULL)
      return strdup(str);

   len = delim_pos - str;
   new_str = malloc(len + 1);
   memcpy(new_str, str, len);
   new_str[len] = '\0'; /* NUL terminate the new string */

   return new_str;
}

int main(void)
{
   char *extracted1 = extract_string("some:string", ':');
   char *extracted2 = extract_string("no delimiter", ':');

   puts(extracted1);
   puts(extracted2);

   /* free the dynamically allocated buffers */
   free(extracted1);
   free(extracted2);

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
some
no delimiter
```

If you don't want to make a copy when the delimiter isn't found, you could alternatively return `NULL`.

Alternatively, if you don't mind mangling your initial string, you could use `strtok` to extract tokens.

Comment: +1 I think this exactly what the OP is expecting; also `strtok` is better option.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is (*labelname)++. You are incrementing the value that's pointed to by labelname and simultaneously assigning to it the value that's pointed to by currentline. If you want to increment the pointers, use *labelname++ and *currentline++

Comment: This would have worked:

`char *GetLabelName(char *currentline){
char *labelname = malloc(sizeof(char)*200);
char *returned = labelname;
while((*labelname++ = *currentline++) != ':');
*--labelname = '\0';
return returned;
}`